# validating upload file extension on Tapestry 5

Tags: tapestry

I am new to Tapestry 5.
I wonder how to validating upload file extension?
For example how to accept on .jpg file?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I'd do it in an `onValidateFromX` event (where X is the form id).

eg:

```
@InjectComponent
private UploadedFile myFile;

@InjectComponent
private Form myForm;

@Inject 
private Messages messages;

void onValidateFromMyForm() {
   if (!myFile.getFileName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")) {
      String errorMsg = messages.get("invalid-file-type", myFile.getFileName());
      myForm.recordError(myFile, errorMsg);
   }
}
```